# php file loaded by ajax function in another php file not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a php file `timer.ajax.php` that is being loaded by a jquery function in `take_test.php` but the modification I made to the SQL query in `timer.ajax.php` is not taking effect. I.e., I want to update `student_class_quiz` such that it is unique. But it updates all my rows.

**timer.ajax.php**:

```
include('dbcon.php');
include('session.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_class_quiz WHERE student_id ='$session_id'")or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$quiz_time = $row['student_quiz_time'];

$sqlp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_quiz")or die(mysql_error());
$rowp = mysql_fetch_array($sqlp);
if($quiz_time <= $rowp['quiz_time'] && $quiz_time > 0){
    mysql_query("UPDATE student_class_quiz 
        SET student_quiz_time = ".$row['student_quiz_time']." - 1 
        WHERE student_id = '$session_id' ")
    or die(mysql_error()); 

    $init = $quiz_time;
    $minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
    $seconds = $init % 60;
    if($init > 59){     
        echo "$minutes minutes and $seconds seconds";
    } else {
        echo "$seconds seconds";
    }
}
```

jQuery function in **take_test.php**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = 1;
    jQuery(".questions-table input").hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        var timer = jQuery("#timer").text();

        jQuery("#timer").load("timer.ajax.php");    
        if(timer == 0){
            jQuery(".questions-table input").hide();
            jQuery("#submit-test").show();
            jQuery("#msg").text("Time's up!!!\nPlease Submit your Answers");
        } else {
            jQuery(".questions-table input").show();
        }
    },990); 
});
```

Comment: 1st. why still using `mysql_*` functions instead of `mysqli_*` or even `pdo`?

Comment: 2nd. what is `$session_id` ?

Comment: 3rd. when you want counting of times, its better to store creation time in database (like unix time stamp) and then count difference between the saved and one actual one - without updating it in the database at all. In your example, user can turn internet off or something similar, and your timer stops at all....

Comment: @Seti.Thanks a lot $session is the session id of the user.I now have my code in single file.By using class_quiz_id or any other variable, it still did not fetch the unique time rather it uses the same timing of a quiz for another quiz taken by the same student in same session

Comment: Can you update the question with new source code?